# Clear recent locations in Calendar (macOS)

Tags: macos, calendar

I moved to a new address (it's almost one year). Every time I add an event at my address (by entering my name in the location) I still get the old one as primary suggestion (although my address is updated in the contacts).

[image]

How do I clear the *Recent Locations*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a simple way as in iOS, where you can just swipe to delete an entry.

Recent Locations (map-location) on macOS are stored in the "corerecents" database here:
 `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.corerecents.recentsd/Data/Library/Recents/Recents`
There are various ways to delete an entry:

- Download a database browser, like [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org), find the entry and delete it.
- Use Terminal (to be found in /Applications/Utilities, or via Spotlight)
  and the command line.

I'm not very versed with `sqlite3`, but the following should delete the "Matteo Corti’s Home" entry:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.corerecents.recentsd/Data/Library/Recents/Recents "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE display_name IS 'Matteo Corti’s Home'"
```

(note: if I type the apostrophe in Terminal, I won't get a result, since the database seems to use `’`, instead of `'`, i.e. not a straight apostrophe.)

If you wanted to clear all entries (including email, phone, urls and instant message recents), you could just delete the database, I would think.